# How to copy the sheet name to a column on the same sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code:

```
Function wrksht() as Variant
wrksht = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End function
```

I am continuously being thrown

> run time error '424' object not found

I have a workbook with several sheets, each having a date on it.

I want to populate the first column on every sheet with its sheet name.

Comment: I assume the first line is merely a typo. How are you using the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function wrksht() as String
  wrksht = ActiveSheet.Name
End function
```

---

UPDATE

---

```
Function DoIt()
  Dim sh As Worksheet

  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    sh.Range("A1") = sh.Name
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo.

Comment: I still don't get the solution I am looking for. I basically have a workbook with several sheets, each having a date on it. I want to populate the first column on every sheet with its sheet name. That is want I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```vb
Sub my_macro
On error resume next
Dim ws As Worksheet 
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Range("A1") = ws.Name 
Next
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The above will work, but I have an easier solution:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

Paste this value (it is a formula, not VBA code) into the cell you wish to populate with the sheet name, and it will magically appear.